# Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC' , Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: jvm, java-10, jvm-crash

I am trying to start a server using jre 10.0.1 64 bit. There is an obvious change in the settings for the JVM in windows start batch files. With the setting of `-XX:+UseParNewGC`  as the reference point of the error what would this need to be changed to in order to get a JVM server start with java 10 versus the java 8 settings I have shown?

The line of code causing the error reference is:

```
set JAVA_PARAMETERS=-XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=5 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=10
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As a follow up to Peter's answer the flag is

```
-XX:+UseG1GC
```

as described at [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out I am sure I am not the first to bring this topic up.

Answer (score 29):

This collectors was deprecated in JDK 9 and removed in JDK 10.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8151084

The new default is the G1 collector and I suggest you see if that suits your needs.

Comment: The flag was removed, but not the collector. ParNew is the default collector for young generation when CMS is selected.

Answer (score 8):

I was getting the same error in elasticsearch. So the best way to resolve it is.

Run

```
sudo nano /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch.in.sh
```

and comment out that VM arg

```
#ES_GC_OPTS="$ES_GC_OPTS -XX:+UseParNewGC"
```

Comment: your answer worked like charm. I also need to comment other ES_GC_OPTS in that if block also

Comment: not work I got error for next line and also comment all other line but elastic search is not staring

Comment: Thank you for this. It greatly helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue by running below command it gets resolved

**set JAVA_PARAMETERS=-XX:+UseG1GC**

Answer (score 0):

Use `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` if you do want to use CMS.