# Unable to run elasticsearch.bat file on Windows due to error in JVM

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jvm

I have been trying to run the elasticsearch batch file from Windows after installing Java but it doesn't run because of "UseParNewGC" error. I have the 10.0.1 version of Java and I have seen in other links that the error has been removed in this version but it still doesn't seem to work. I have set the path variable $JAVA_HOME. Here is the error. One of the links I did refer was - [Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC' , Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49962437/unrecognized-vm-option-useparnewgc-error-could-not-create-the-java-virtual) but it wasn't useful

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC' , Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49962437/unrecognized-vm-option-useparnewgc-error-could-not-create-the-java-virtual)

Comment: Yes I did check that but the answers for that do not apply to this. They suggest that the error would be handled with the Java update but it hasn't been so in my case.