# I upgraded Java and now Tomcat service won't start

Tags: java, tomcat8

I recently upgraded Java and now Tomcat service won't start. This is on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server. Tomcat is version 8.5. I upgraded from Java 7 to Java 11, Azul Zulu 7 to Azul Zulu 11. When running `systemctl status tomcat85` I see the following not particularly helpful output:

[image]

Although the service won't seem to work, I can start Tomcat manually with the following command:

```
/opt/tomcat85/bin/startup.sh
```

These are the contents of the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat 8.5 Servlet Container
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
User=tomcat85
Group=tomcat85
Type=forking
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/zulu-11-amd64
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat85/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat85
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat85
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/tomcat85
WorkingDirectory=/opt/tomcat85
ExecStart=/opt/tomcat85/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat85/bin/shutdown.sh
#Restart=on-failure
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
LimitNOFILE=65536
SyslogIdentifier=tomcat85

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Running `journalctl -xe` provides no meritorious information.

catalina.out reveals the following error:

[image]

I'm not sure where to go next with troubleshooting this issue. There are several seemingly related discussions on Stack but none have provided a solution as of yet. Any help is appreciated and I'm happy to add more information as requested.

Comment: Check if under `/usr/lib/jvm/zulu-11-amd64` is a complete JDK11. What gives `$ /usr/lib/jvm/zulu-11-amd64/bin/java -version`.

Comment: @PeterMmm thank you. I ran the command and it gave the following output: `openjdk version "11.0.18" 2023-01-17 LTS`.

Comment: Nothing interesting in `/opt/tomcat85/logs`  or syslog ?

Comment: @PeterMmm, I just checked catalina.out and posted the error above: "Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'.

Comment: Search where does `UseParNewGC` comes from, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49962437/unrecognized-vm-option-useparnewgc-error-could-not-create-the-java-virtual for replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer thanks to some good feedback here in this post. The problem was several deprecated entries in the EnvironmentFile:
/etc/default/tomcat85

```
JAVA_OPTS="-server -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:PermSize=1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xms16384m -Xmx20480m"
```

One of the errant entries was:
-XX:+UseParNewGC
The updated entry is:
-XX:+UseG1GC

Additionally the following entries needed to be removed:
UseConcMarkSweepGC
PermSize
MaxPermSize